# angular onclick invokes twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I tried to create image file input to browse photo. The input had been trigger through inline button click using normal javascript instead of AngularJS itself. It didn't work for me using Angular.

I had used `angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.imageInput')).click() or trigger('click') or triggerHandler('click')`, but no luck. So I'm using normal javascript and it works but browse image photo pop up twice instead of one. I had tried event prevent default before and after still doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputImage" style="display:none" type="file" file-model="myProfileImage" name="..."/>
<button click="uploadImage(myProfileImage)"  class="editPhoto">Confirm</button>
```

Tried different approaches but does not work:

```
<button onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('inputImage').click();" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().previewFile(this)" class="editPhoto" >Change</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('inputImage').click(function(e){e.preventDefault()});"  class="editPhoto">Change</button>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Problem**

> Pop up TWICE when input invoked

Comment: I'm not very familiar with inline JS, but I'm fairly certain it's because you're calling .click again when the button has been clicked, remove the .click completely.

Comment: why don't you use ng-click?

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou replace onclick with ng-click? Even I tried that it does not popup. If ng-click trigger controller function, angular.element I had tried doesn't work for me. It show nothing without error.

Comment: @TomJohnson No, it doesn't trigger without .click()

Comment: try: $event.stopImmediatePropagation() to stop the event immediately after your onclick callback. My question is, why should this ever happen? To call both of the callbacks of onclick buttons from one action

Comment: @Eirini Graonidou It still does not work for me. But I find another approach, but I don't know why it works. `onclick="alert('LOL');document.getElementById('inputImage').click()"` will trigger only one time.